# Drawing a very thin line on UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiview

So I got `UIView` at the top of my app and I want to draw a thin line at the bottom of it, a very similar line that act as a seperator in `UITableView`. I currently have a `UIView` that has height of 1px set in IB, but when I compare that line to the seperator in `UITableView` it has higher height. Is there any good way to draw a thin line inside a `UIView`?

Comment: set it's alpha to 0.5 or less and it will look thiner

Comment: I think you you should go for label and change the background color of it. Don't write anything on label.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give the frame of your line view a `height` (or `width`) of `0.5` and set the `backgroundColor` to `[UIColor lightGrayColor]`.

**Edit:** For non-retina you might change the height/width to `(1.0 / [UIScreen mainScreen].scale)`

This will result in 0.5 on retina and 1.0 on non-retina displays.

Comment: This will look bad on non-retina devices, but if you're only supporting iPhone on ios7, that's not a problem.

Comment: @Marc, is it possible to set 0.5 in non-retina display?

Comment: It is possible, but I don't know how it will look like. That's why I posted an alternative formula. Don't hardcode `0.5` but use the formula instead.

Comment: @jrturton The first iPad mini supports iOS 7, and that's non-retina.

Comment: @thisiscrazy4 true, but we're talking about iPhones

Answer (score 3):

Just insert inside your `UIView`

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

and inside `drawRect:` add this and specify the height of the line

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0f);
    //start at this point
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, self.frame.size.height);
    //draw to this point
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,
                            self.frame.size.width,
                            self.frame.size.height);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    // and now draw the Path!
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

}
```

and you'll get a line like the red one here

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this for your view. this code will draw a 2px red color border to your view.

Add `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` to your view.

```
CALayer *bottomBorder = [CALayer layer];
bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, myview.frame.size.height - 2, myview.frame.size.width, 2.0f);
bottomBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
[myview.layer addSublayer:bottomBorder];
```